# Rails 4 API Versioning recommended practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

The Rails default scaffold includes methods to allow you to publish an API, allowing users to interact with the same controllers via both HTML and JSON.

Generating a new scaffold for a product model with `body` and `url` with `rails generate scaffold products body:string url:string` will make something like:

```
# GET /products
# GET /products.json
def index
  @products = Product.all
end
```

And generate both an HTML view but also `index.json.jbuilder`:

```
json.array!(@products) do |product|
  json.extract! product, :body, :url
  json.url product_url(product, format: :json)
end
```

Rails is clearly automatically generating all of the code to let us expose this model as an API as well as offer our standard HTML interface.

My question(s) are:

- What is the recommended practice to version something like this?
- Is this method to exposing the API really the expected practice?
- All of the other resources I've found suggest separate namespaced controllers to expose the API actions, so why expose JSON and HTML in the default setup?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the railscast here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning?view=asciicast. Should clear most of your doubts.